# Get Selected value from multiple value in dropdownlist Select2

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-select2

This example is totally what I'm looking for
https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/339115/Searchable-multiselect-DropDownList-from-Database-using-jQuery-Select2-Plugin-in-ASPNet/

And after choose all the countries needed, I will click Submit button. My problem is on how to get all the selected value from ddl1.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".js-example-placeholder-single").select2({
        placeholder: "Select",
        allowClear: true
        });
    });

</script></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<h2>
    Upload Attachment
</h2>
<div>
    <br /><br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Attachment :  " class="form-control"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" class="form-control"/>
    <br /><br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Plase select Staff No :  " class="form-control"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" Width="300px" runat="server" multiple="multiple" CssClass="form-control js-example-placeholder-single" ToolTip="Select " OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br /><br />

    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Attachment" OnClick="btnUpload_Click"/>

    <br /><br />
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

And this is C# code behind

```
private void PopulateDropDownList()
{
    
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_User";
    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        ddl1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddl1.DataTextField = "IDName";
        ddl1.DataValueField = "StaffNo";
        ddl1.DataBind();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "";
    string rnonow = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss");
    GetUploadRno();
    rnoUploaded = rno;

    Label4.Text = ddl1.SelectedValue; //this is where i'm stuck on how to call the ddl1 selected value. This code just only get the 1st selected value only eg : Brazil only not the other 2 below.
   
    //below is my trial to get the selected value but fail
    //foreach (ListItem item in ddl1.Items)
    //{
    //    if (item.Selected)
    //    {
    //       insert statement here

    //    }
    //}
}
```

Please help. Thank you

[image]

Comment: You need to post your markup as well plus it would be helpful for us to see how the data is being saved on the DOM, perhaps, inspect the element and share the markup from the browser as well.

Comment: @JamshaidK. i've added my code

Comment: You still have not added the DOM Source that is in the browser after rendering. You need to inspect the multi select and share that source too

Comment: Right click on the textbox and click inspect element. Then copy that html and share it here.

Comment: you want to fill automatically the select2 with the multiple selected items? or  you want to trap values from select2 box?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use DropDownList for multi-select. Use ListBox e.g.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ddl" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="form-control js-example-placeholder-single" ToolTip="Select">
</asp:ListBox>
```

In code-behind:

```
foreach (ListItem item in ddl.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
       var text = item.Text;
       var value = item.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by creating a field, and jQuery store the data into it.

```
$('[id*=ddl1]').on('change', function () {
            $('[id*=hfSelected]').val($(this).val());
        });

<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelected" runat="server" />
```